# Running Ember-CLI on VirtualBox

Tags: ember-cli, livereload, broccolijs

After a great deal work tinkering I have a **mostly** working copy of an **ember-cli** project running on a guest **Ubuntu VirtualBox**.  One of my goals was to run the code inside a **Shared Folder** and I have it mostly working.

There are a number of hacks ahem, *workarounds* to get this far.
1. Enable symlinks on Virtualbox Shared Folders
2. Forward LiveReload port from Guest to Host
3. Replace the PROJECT/tmp folder with a symlink to the local Guest filesystem

**What works...**
When I edit a file in my ember project from the **guest**, the server sees the change and auto reloads.

**What does not work....**
When I edit a file in my ember project from the **host**, the server does **NOT** see the change and does nothing.

Why oh why does the ember-cli stack not detect changes made from the Host.  I can't even point to the culprit.  Is it Broccoli, livereload, node or my mother in law that is giving me trouble?

Comment: I don't fully understand your post, so this is a shot in the dark... I get this error/warning when I run `ember serve`: `"Could not find watchman, falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events"`. So perhaps the problem is with either `NodeWatcher` or `watchman` not detecting file system changes on your host?

Comment: I think you are in the neighborhood but it seems the problem here is in using Virtualbox's Shared Folder feature.  It's a bit of black magic to share a file on the HOST to the GUEST and vice versa.  So the *Watch* service (running on guest) doesn't detect file changes made on host and propagated through VirtualBox Shared Folder feature.

Comment: You are likely to have better luck using samba instead of shared folders.